# Prove that the conjugate of a proper ideal is its inverse

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm having trouble with this question:
[image]

More specifically, I know that for a proper $\mathcal{O}$-ideal $\mathfrak{a}$,

$$\mathfrak{a}\overline{\mathfrak{a}} = N(\mathfrak{a}) \mathcal{O}$$

but i don't know why $N(\alpha) \mathcal{O}$ equals $\mathcal{O}$. Obviously $N(\mathfrak{a})$ is an integer, but why multiplication by an integers doens't change the order $\mathcal{O}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N(\mathfrak a) \mathcal O$ is a principal ideal, and the class group is ideals *modulo principal ideals*.